# Error while adding library https://github.com/Romancha/android-material-play-pause-view-button

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, github, gradle

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.romancha:MaterialPlayPauseViewButton:1.0.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.romancha:MaterialPlayPauseViewButton:1.0.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.romancha:MaterialPlayPauseViewButton:1.0.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.8.1'
    }
```

i have tried invalid caches/restart and also gradle offline toogle even restarting project.But showing same error.

I have two dependency for the same

```
//PlayButton
    implementation 'com.github.romancha:MaterialPlayPauseViewButton:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.Romancha:android-material-play-pause-view-button:-SNAPSHOT'
```

i have used both alternatively but having error for the same. The snapshot dependancy i took from (https://jitpack.io/#Romancha/android-material-play-pause-view-button/-SNAPSHOT).

Comment: For better resolution, please post your App's gradle with the dependencies you have added. Meanwhile, you can try with "File -> Invalid Caches and restart" from the Android Studio menu.

Comment: implementation 'com.github.romancha:MaterialPlayPauseViewButton:1.0.1'  this dependency i have used but i got this error log (Could not HEAD 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/romancha/MaterialPlayPauseViewButton/1.0.1/MaterialPlayPauseViewButton-1.0.1.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized)

Answer (score 0):

Bintray and version 1.0+ is no more available.

Try from readme https://github.com/Romancha/android-material-play-pause-view-button

Add the following to your project level build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
    }
}
```

Add this to your app build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.Romancha:android-material-play-pause-view-button:2.3'
}
```